# Remote desktops with RedHat "Server" package?

Tags: virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I'm investigating options for a small corporate virtualisation setup.  We specialise in scientific computing and would like to consolidate our resources. We are keen on KVM, since it looks like it performs well with multiple vCPU per VM.

I'm confused by the RedHat KVM offering.  We don't want to virtualise everyone's existing desktops but we do want to have additional virtual desktops, not just ssh access.  With "RH Virtualisation for Servers" (much cheaper than the Desktop offering) can we still have the virtual GUI desktops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly. [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/) can be served from a virtual machine running on top of RHEL, and then you can have the virtual desktops connect via XDMCP to another virtual machine running on the server that does the actual hard work.

Comment: This looks good, but I guess we couldn't serve up windows desktops too.  At least not unless the RH virt Server offering has some kind of remote desktop capability.

Comment: `rdesktop` is capable of connecting to Terminal Server. It can be run once the virtual desktop is up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to decide whether you need VDI or Server virtualization, contact Red Hat, and they will provide information to clear your doubts

Answer (score 0):

Your environment seems to be a good match for NX/NoMachine - See here: http://www.nomachine.com/